# Unity3d crashes when trying to change platform or building after upgrading to win10

Tags: unity-game-engine, crash, cross-platform, windows-10

http://prntscr.com/cfakce this is what happened when I'm entering any script,  when I'm changing to mobile input this show up http://prntscr.com/cfalpw.

Whenever I'm trying to build the project or changing platform it crashes.

I changed my win7 to win10 (had to) and I think it may screwed my project but I'm not really sure, tried to search on Google for those errors and found nothing.

Someone told me on the Unity forum that it had something to do with UnityEditor but didn't had really idea how to fix it.

When I had win7 (before the change) everything worked perfectly fine.

Any ideas?

Unity version: Unity 5.4.0f3 (64-bit) thought it might help.

new: When I'm writing using at the start of any script it doesn't complete it to Unity.Engine or Unity.Editor it doesn't even have this option, like it got deleted or something. How do I bring back those Unity.editor and engine? I think it's the real problem :)

Another thing is that when I got win10 the C drive is now F and I've got new SSD drive which is the new C, everything stayed on the C drive but they didn't work or was used perfectly, so I redownloaded everything like Skype, steam, Origin and of course UNITY, the project folder I dragged to my desktop and then opened the game folder on this Unity I downloaded, I think that's what made the problem because when i enter Unity and press open, and going back to F drive>users>myname>dekstop>UNITY>mygame and open it in that path instead of what i have dragged (which it the same folder but on different place) it let me switch platform, does not let me build but at least it's not crashing just giving me the same errors without crashing, i don't know if this has something to do with but just gave the info cause maybe you will find this helpful to help me.

Comment: Could you please add some more structure to your question? It's a block of plaintext that's hard to extract important details from.

Comment: It look like your question went through gulp. Put some spaces in it and make it more understable.

Comment: Yes. You spelled screwed up wrong

Comment: i hope now it's better :)